# How to add a vector to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of shape (13,10)  I want to add vector of zeros till the shape becomes 20 rows and 10 columns

```
    a=([[1,2,3,.......,10],
        [1,2,3,.......,10],
                    .
                    .   
        [13,14,.......,10]]). # this is the 13th row
   b=([0,0,0,....0])         # has length 10
```

I want to pad "a" with "b" at the beginning till the "a" has 20 rows

Comment: You may check out [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
z = np.zeros((13, 10))
x = np.zeros((1, 10))
y = np.vstack((z, x))
y.shape
(14, 10)
```

Check [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: Op wants an output with 20 rows (padding the remaining ones with 0), not 14

Answer (score 0):

Try `np.row_stack`:

```py
a = np.ones((13,10))
b = np.zeros(10)
a_pad = np.row_stack((a,b))
a_pad
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Do this until you get the length you want. maybe a `while` loop or something even simpler just stack `b = np.zeros((7,10))` to get the 20 you want

Answer (score 0):

First we can initialize a matrix filled with zeros for the desired shape, then copy `a` to the first 13 rows. In any case, we have to form a new matrix since there's no way to fiddle around with already existing matrices/vectors since we need to allocate more memory for the extra null rows.

Below you can find an example demonstration:

```
# inputs
In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [31]: b
Out[31]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

---

```
# initialize a zero array for the desired shape
In [32]: appended = np.zeros((20, b.shape[0]))

# copy `a` to first few rows
In [33]: appended[:a.shape[0], :] = a

# expected output
In [34]: appended
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```